# Move drupal site from web to local host

Tags: backups

I have a site that's already on the host.
So what I want to do is to put in on my PC , and so I could edit it. 
I have already installed WAMP and download a backup with the site from the host, and downloaded the DB from the host also.

What I have to do next?

Answer (score 1):

1. Put your project in WAMP's www folder.
2. Start wamp and make sure both aparche and mySQL is up and running
3. Go to phpmyadmin http://localhost/phpmyadmin
4. Create a new database and import your database backup
5. Go to wamp/www/[your project folder]/sites/default and edit settings.php file.
6. Set database connection and $baseurl in settings.php file.
7. Go to http://localhost/[your project folder]

Comment: Thanks for your help. 
It didn't work for me, in browser appears an error:  
"Server at localhost Port 80"

what should I change in $baseurl ? it's commented by default

Comment: Can you just check C:\wamp\bin\apache\[your apache version]\conf\httpd.conf for the port currently using. It will be something like Listen 0.0.0.0:80. If it is not 80 it can be 8080, 8888. Once you find the port try to access http://localhost:8080, or http://localhost:8888

Answer (score 0):

Now, you need to add your DB credentials on your local environment to MySQL. Using phpmyadmin is the easier way to that. After that you would have to pull all your website files in the wamp root directory.

Once you import the database and have the files in the root directory you can visit your website at localhost on any browser.

Comment: Thank for your replay.
I've done all those steps, but next error message is appearing:"Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80"

Answer (score 0):

Double check that your permissions for your files and folders are accessible by your wamp server. I always forget that step.